# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access, ios13

I am maintaining a project that has been done by a previous developer and it has start crashing a lot on iOS 13.

The crash is always the same but in different areas: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee3a48f88)`

Please note this is still working in previous iOS versions, just **not** in iOS 13.

The issue is caused when is trying to access a `UIView`. For example, it crashes in the following piece of code in the line `cellView.layoutIfNeeded()`. It's weird cause the `_view` of course exists, as it goes into the `if let`.

```
if let cellView = _view as? UITableViewCell {
    cellView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

I'll also add a picture from the Xcode:

[image]

I have the feeling the the crash is related of how this `_view` is treated. 
You pass the view the following way:
`objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &theKey) as? CustomView`

The way this CustomView is set:

```
 var customView: CustomView? {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, & theKey) as? CustomView
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, & theKey, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }
```

Has anyone seen something similar to this?

I have looked also at the release notes of ios 13 and I haven't found anything related.

Thank you

Comment: I encountered this issue after updating to ios13.  I believe, cellView needs to be defined as optional. You can then have cellView?.layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: @DarylWong That's just a shorthand way of writing the same code. That is, unless `_view as? UITableViewCell` is successful if `_view` is `nil` which it shouldn't be.

Comment: How do you set the association? Somewhere you must be calling `objc_setAssociatedObject`. What is the [association policy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/objc_associationpolicy?language=objc)?

Comment: @JeremyP please see the updated question with the setAssociatedObject and the policy.

Comment: @JoanCardona is it possible that the same value of `theKey` is used by two different object associations?

Comment: No, I already checked that @JeremyP.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the `_view` property to something less generic.

I recently ran into an issue with a property named `_containerView` where it looks like due to some changes in how UIKit works (it's written in ObjC) and dynamic method dispatch, UIKit is probably using your variable instead if its own which is causing the crash.

Comment: I just changed it but the issue is still there :/

Comment: How is the `_view` property defined?

Comment: @objc var _view: UIView?